# getting weird result at redraw method when subclass UIView, Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

My `TNContainer` is subclassed of UIView and I am doing like the following to `drawRect` method

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"UINavigationBarBlackOpaqueBackground.png"]
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.containerView      =   [[TNContainer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 10)];
    self.navigationBar.topItem.titleView    =   self.containerView;

}
```

in my `TNContainer.m`, I am doing ( putting some statements  to print out the bounds and frame)

```
#import "TNContainer.h"

@implementation TNContainer

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    NSLog(@"frame at initWithFrame is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
    NSLog(@"bound at initWithFrame is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
    return self;
}

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    NSLog(@"frame at drawRect is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
    NSLog(@"bounds at drawRect is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));

    CGRect rectangle        = self.bounds;
    CGContextRef context    = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
}
```

It is very interesting that the bounds of the frame in `initWithFrame` and `drawRect` are totally different

```
2013-09-25 16:19:47.926 TNSegmentController[10458:a0b] frame at initWithFrame is {{0, 0}, {100, 10}}
2013-09-25 16:19:47.928 TNSegmentController[10458:a0b] bound at initWithFrame is {{0, 0}, {100, 10}}
2013-09-25 16:19:47.934 TNSegmentController[10458:a0b] frame at drawRect is {{110, 17}, {100, 10}}
2013-09-25 16:19:47.934 TNSegmentController[10458:a0b] bounds at drawRect is {{0, 0}, {100, 10}}
```

Why I am getting `{{110, 17}, {100, 10}}` for the frame in `drawRect()`....

Any ideas about this ?

Comment: does redraw called even if you remove self.navigationBar.topItem.titleView    =   self.containerView;

Comment: Expected that. explanation on Tim answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's not strange at all - in fact, it's to be expected. At `-initWithFrame:` time, you pass in a frame with origin `(0,0)`. That frame is duly logged in your UIView subclass.

By the time that view goes to draw, however, you've assigned it to be the `titleView` of a navigation bar; the bar has likely added your view as its own subview and repositioned it to be centered. Your first drawing request doesn't come in until after all that has happened, and it's why you see a different origin - `(110,17)` - in your `-drawRect:` override.

(You'll note that your original size is preserved, which I imagine is the thing you really care about. Changing the origin of the view - and therefore the frame - is the desired behavior for using a custom title view.)

Answer (score 0):

because "bounds" are in relation to itself. "frame" is a reference to its location in the super view. as @Tim mentions, if the super view changes the location, the "frame" value will change but the internal "bounds" will not, assuming the super view did not adjust the size.